# run graphical applications using a script under windowmaker

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get a simple .sh script running under windowmaker that runs a set of X apps after asking for user input. All my attempts were futile; the terminal window evaporates after asking the question and the apps simply won't run. I've attempted running this script by typing its path on an X console and it works perfectly, but when I run the icon it won't.

These are my 2 attempts;

```
echo "this or that? [a, b] "
read input
if [[ $input == "a" || $input == "A" ]]; then
/path/to/app1 "/file/to/open" &
/path/to/app2 "/file/to/open" &
/path/to/app3 "/file/to/open" &
path/to/app4 &
else
/path/to/app5 "/file/to/open" &
/path/to/app6 "/file/to/open" &
/path/to/app7 "/file/to/open" &
path/to/app8 &

fi
```

```
read -p  "this or that? [a, b] " doit 

case $doit in
     a|A)

    /path/to/app1 "/file/to/open" &
    /path/to/app2 "/file/to/open" &
    /path/to/app3 "/file/to/open" &
    path/to/app4 &
    b|B)
    /path/to/app5 "/file/to/open" &
    /path/to/app6 "/file/to/open" &
    /path/to/app7 "/file/to/open" &
    path/to/app8 &
;;
esac
```

In windowmaker's settings I created an icon that runs xterm -e "/path/to/script.sh". I don't know what else to do. I hope someone could help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of error do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions that wouldn't fit into a comment block.

First, capture some debugging:

- right after you've read in the user's input, echo the date and the input value to stdout, eg:

`` read ...
    echo `date`" : input = $input" # or $doit ``

- modify your icon to dump stdout/stderr to a file, eg:

`xterm -e "/path/to/script.sh >> /path/to/script.out 2>&1"`

After you run a failed test, check `/path/to/script.out` for any (hopefully useful) messages ...

- if you don't see the `date/input` message, and there are no error messages, then you've got a problem with the `xterm -e` call (ie, you're not even getting to the script call)
- if you do see the `date/input` message, or a script-related error message, then you know the `xterm -e` call was successful and you can focus on the content of the script ...

A couple issues with the scripts as they now exist:

- you appear to be missing a leading `/` for the app4/app8 calls, ie, they should look like:

`/path/to/app4 &
    /path/to/app8 &`

- for `case` statements, each option test should end with a double semicolon (`;;`); while you've done this for the `b|B)` test, you're missing it for the `a|A)` test, so update the script like such:

`a|A) ...
         path/to/app4 & ;;`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I actually got the apps to launch, simply using doing wait in the end of each block, like so:

```
echo "this or that? [a, b] "
read input
if [[ $input == "a" || $input == "A" ]]; then
/path/to/app1 "/file/to/open" &
/path/to/app2 "/file/to/open" &
/path/to/app3 "/file/to/open" &
path/to/app4 &
wait
else
/path/to/app5 "/file/to/open" &
/path/to/app6 "/file/to/open" &
/path/to/app7 "/file/to/open" &
path/to/app8 &
wait
fi
```

I do have another question that's unrelated to this and I'm gonna ask in a bit.